# Access violation writing locating

Tags: c++, access-violation

I cannot figure out what is wrong with my code.  I used add watches to make sure the information was being read correctly and inputted into the array.  The error I'm getting is:

> Access violation writing location.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
//string name;
//double id = 0;
int numQ = 0;
int numA = 0;

string temp;
string arrayQ[50];
string arrayA[50];

fstream SaveFile;
SaveFile.open("TestBank.txt", ios::in);
while (!SaveFile.eof())
{
    getline(SaveFile, temp, '#'); 
    if (temp.length() > 5)
    {
        arrayQ[numQ] = temp;
        numQ++;
    }
    else
    {
        arrayA[numA] = temp;
        numA++;
    }
}
SaveFile.close();

cout << "The question is\n" << arrayQ[0] << endl;
cout << "The answer is\n" << arrayA[0] << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you have more than 50 question lines or more than 50 answer lines?

Comment: My best guess is that `numQ` or/and `numA` gets > 49. Can you check it?

Comment: No I have exactly 50 lines.  numQ and numA both get to 50.  This is what one of the lines looks like that I'm reading in:  CD stands for collective disk?#FALSE#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you shouldn't loop on eof in C++.

Then you should ensure that `numQ` and `numA` do not get out of bounds, as their value depend on the file content:

```
...
while (getline(SaveFile, temp, '#'))
{  
    if (temp.length() > 5)
    {
        if (numQ>=50) 
            cerr << "Ouch ! numQ=" <<numQ<<endl; 
        else arrayQ[numQ] = temp;
        numQ++;
    }
    else
    {
        if (numA>=50) 
            cerr << "Ouch ! numA=" <<numA<<endl; 
        else arrayA[numA] = temp;
        numA++;
    }
}
```

Finally, you could consider using `vector<string>` instead of string arrays.  In this case you would just `push_back()` the strings in the right vector without having to worry about a predetermined size.

Comment: I haven't learned either of those yet, but I'll try reading ahead and see if I understand those.